# Exiftool move files to directory with filename minus last 5 characters

Tags: exiftool

How can i move files in folders with same filename but stripped last 5 characters of filename?

```
\one_EXP0
\one_EXP1
\one_EXP2

\two_EXP0
\two_EXP1
\two_EXP2
```

Need to move them in folders names same as filename with stripped "_EXP*" from the end.

```
\one\one_EXP0
\one\one_EXP1
\one\one_EXP2

\two\two_EXP0
\two\two_EXP1
\two\two_EXP2
```

Why this does not work exiftool `"-directory<%d\%f\%f.%e" DIR`

**EDIT:** Just realized that prior to moving files i also need to put the number at the end of each file in reverse order than it currently is, no idea how to achieve this with ExifTool

Renaming them from

```
\one_EXP0.dng
\one_EXP1.dng
\one_EXP2.dng
\one_EXP3.dng
\one_EXP4.dng
```

rename then to

```
\one_EXP4.dng
\one_EXP3.dng
\one_EXP2.dng
\one_EXP1.dng
\one_EXP0.dng
```

Comment: [Same question](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=15402.msg82727#msg82727) on the Exiftool forums, which is answered by the author of exiftool

Comment: @StarGeek  I have updated requirements a bit